# Passing object to another WPF Window C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, object

I need to find a way for an object which is stored in a collection to be able to use it in another Window for the purpose of displaying the values of the object in a listbox.

My code contains the following:

Class to store the values of the object

```
public class Customer
{       
    private string _firstName;

    public string firstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }
```

Main window with methods and buttons to add, find delete etc the object which also contains this line of code:

```
    private void btnListAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listAll displayAll = new listAll();            
        displayAll.Show();
    }
```

This opens new window (listAll) and I want to be able use the customer object in listAll window

And finaly this is how my listAll window looks:

```
public partial class listAll : Window
{

    public listAll()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void lstAll_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have figured out a way to be able to use customer object in new window. I just had to add this:

```
using BusinessObjects;
```

but now I am stuck on how to populate my listBox with the values from the customer object.

Comment: You can access main window anywhere in your application by `System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow`, then you simply cast it to the class of your main window and access customer property.

Comment: Can you construct the object that contains the data and pass it into your window's constructor? i.e. when you call `new listAll(dataObject)`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to create  Service provider class that will hold the data. Use MEF or Unity to export it. Then import it on any window you want in the entire process.

The data - your list - will be created and exist once on the Service provider class and will be shared across.